# studying the series $\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \tan (\frac{n}{1+n^3})$

Tags: real-analysis

studying the series $\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \tan (\frac{n}{1+n^3})$.

The series has got a sense for each natural number.

$1+n^3>n, \forall n \in N \Rightarrow \frac{n}{1+n^3}<1,\forall n \in N\Rightarrow \tan \frac{n}{1+n^3} $ tends to 0 as $n \in N$ increases.

So all the elements are positive and tends to 0.

$$\tan \frac{n}{1+n^3} \sim \frac{\sin\frac{n}{1+n^3} }{\cos\frac{n}{1+n^3}} \sim \frac{\frac{n}{1+n^3} }{\cos\frac{n}{1+n^3}} \sim \frac{n}{1+n^3} <\frac{n}{n^3}= \frac{1}{n^2}$$

$\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges $\Rightarrow $ the original series converges.

Is it right?

Comment: Yes, this is right.

Comment: Yes, but it can be made shorter: $\tan u$ is equivalent to $u$ near $0$, so you can have directly $\;\tan\frac n{1+n^3}\sim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{1+n^3}\sim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: @Bernard thanks

Answer (score 2):

From $$x\leq\tan x\leq \frac{4x}{\pi} \quad \left(0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

We get $$0\leq \frac{n}{1+n^3}\leq \tan \left(\frac{n}{1+n^3}\right) \leq \frac{4n}{\pi(1+n^3)} \leq \frac{4}{\pi n^2}$$

So original series converges by comparison test.